# Expression of type collection.T doesn't conform to expected type of MongoDBObject

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using CashBah library for MongoDB in Scala (Play framework). Following is the code, I am getting the

> Expression of type collection.T doesn't conform to expected type of
>   MongoDBObject

```
val result : MongoDBObject = collection.findOne(query) get
```

What is the wrong with this line of code?

My method is as following:

```
def getUserID(username : String, password : String) : Option[Int] = {
    val collection : MongoCollection = MongoDBConfiguration.mongoCollections("","")
    val query = MongoDBObject("username" -> username, "password" -> password)
    val result : MongoDBObject = collection.findOne(query) get

  }
```

Here `MongoDBConfiguration` is an object which has a method `mongoCollections`

Comment: What is type `T` in your case? Show us the entire method.

Comment: Sure please find updated question

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I solved the problem by import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._ Can you explain how this solve the problem?